# F# | Какой тип функции имеет функция с параметром функцией?

Tags: функции, f#

Допустим, у меня есть функция, суммирует 2 числа:

```
let add (x: float32, y: float32) : float32 = 
    x + y

printfn "%f" add(x, y)
```

Здесь тип функции таков:

> float32 -> float32 -> float32

Но что если я потребую в параметрах функции какую либо функцию, и вызову её?

```
let add (x: float32, y: float32) =
    x + y

let operation func (x: float32, y: float32) =
    func x y
```

Какой тип функции у функции operation?

Comment: Вы можете легко посмотреть тип любой сущности в F# interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип вашей функции `operation` вот такой:

```
(float32 -> float32 -> 'a) -> float32 * float32 -> 'a
```

Comment: Вроде ж там тупл? Или в F# сделали autosplatting?

Comment: Серьезно? Можно по-подробней рассказать почему функция имеет тип *float32*

Comment: @VladD отсутствие каррирования выглядело бы странным в ML-подобном языке

Comment: @GamerDreemurr_X а где вы увидели что тип функции - float32?

Comment: @VladD понял. Ну, я исходил из того, что автор не наврал в начальных условиях. Возможно, вам лучше написать свой ответ если вы знаете язык.

Comment: Я имел в виду вот что: https://pastebin.com/N0bh7jv6. Автор описал функцию, которая принимает tuple на вход.

Comment: То, что он имел в виду, должно выглядеть как `let add (x:float32) (y:float32) = x + y`, это производит `val add : x:float32 -> y:float32 -> float32`. Но я тоже не спец по языку. Я имел в виду сплаттинг тупла-параметра в (каррированную) пару аргументов (простите неточность выражения)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fYYvZu5N (что в общем-то логично, т. к. тип возвращаемого значения неизвестен).